# Send keys in selenium webdriver with javascript

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, sendkeys

[image]I can't seem to get the sendKeys function to work. I am using selenium webdriver, and js to send keys. any help would be appreciated.

```
it("Apply text input", async function() {
await dashboardPage.run();

let inputs = await dashboardPage.componentsByClass('ace-content');
// identify the Element to put text into

for (let i in inputs){
  console.log(await results[i].sendKeys("https://www.google.com",Key.RETURN);    }
  await driver.sleep(4000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `console.log`. Send Keys  two times.

```
element.sendKeys("https://www.google.com")
element.sendKeys(driver.Key.ENTER)
```

Comment: `var applyLinks = await dashboardPage.componentsByCssSelector(".MuiInputBase-input"); 
        applyLinks[0].click(); 
        applyLinks[0].sendKeys("red");`

I can get this to input red but not press enter. What do you think? I tried (red.ENTER)

Comment: thanks so much! I kept doing (driver.Keys.Enter) and I didnt specify key at the top to require selenium webdriver.